# Add a Padding inside Children<Widget> in Flutter

Tags: flutter, margin, padding, flutter-layout

I've a gridview that contains some images.

but you know, it's so close each other and I want give them a space one of other.

but I still cant make them .

I've try to make some experiments.
but it still give me nothing.
the problem is the padding is inside the gridview.
if i put them (all items) in 1 container, 1 container, 1 container etc, there are a lot of container inside the gridview.

```
`Container(
            margin: new EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
            color: Colors.red,
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            child: GridView.count(
              physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              shrinkWrap: true,
              crossAxisCount: 6,
              children: <Widget>[
                Image.asset('images/user.png', width: 30.0),
                Image.asset('images/user.png', width: 30.0),
                Image.asset('images/user.png', width: 30.0),
                Image.asset('images/user.png', width: 30.0),
                Image.asset('images/user.png', width: 30.0),
                Image.asset('images/user.png', width: 30.0),
                Image.asset('images/user.png', width: 30.0),
                Image.asset('images/user.png', width: 30.0),
                Image.asset('images/user.png', width: 30.0),
                Image.asset('images/user.png', width: 30.0),
                Image.asset('images/user.png', width: 30.0),
              ],
            ),
          ),
```

here the preview: https://i.stack.imgur.com/W0RS5.jpg`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for the space to each other in `gridview` set the **mainAxisSpacing** & **crossAxisSpacing** properties of gridview ,

```
GridView.count(
          physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          shrinkWrap: true,
          crossAxisCount: 6,
          mainAxisSpacing: 8.0,
          crossAxisSpacing: 8.0,
          children: <Widget>[
            Image.asset('images/user.png', width: 30.0),
            Image.asset('images/user.png', width: 30.0),
            Image.asset('images/user.png', width: 30.0),
            Image.asset('images/user.png', width: 30.0),
            Image.asset('images/user.png', width: 30.0),
            Image.asset('images/user.png', width: 30.0),
            Image.asset('images/user.png', width: 30.0),
            Image.asset('images/user.png', width: 30.0),
            Image.asset('images/user.png', width: 30.0),
            Image.asset('images/user.png', width: 30.0),
            Image.asset('images/user.png', width: 30.0),
          ],
        ),
```

Comment: thank you so much for your answer. its work for me.
very helpful answer. god bless you thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You can add `SizedBox` between children.

```
SizedBox(
  width: 200.0,
  height: 300.0,
)
```

Your code can be edited into

```
Container(
    margin: new EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
    color: Colors.red,
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
    child: GridView.count(
      physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      shrinkWrap: true,
      crossAxisCount: 6,
      children: <Widget>[
        Image.asset('images/user.png', width: 30.0),
        SizedBox(width: 10,height: 10,),
        Image.asset('images/user.png', width: 30.0),
        SizedBox(width: 10,height: 10,),
        Image.asset('images/user.png', width: 30.0),
        SizedBox(width: 10,height: 10,),
        Image.asset('images/user.png', width: 30.0),
        SizedBox(width: 10,height: 10,),
        Image.asset('images/user.png', width: 30.0),
        SizedBox(width: 10,height: 10,),
        Image.asset('images/user.png', width: 30.0),
        SizedBox(width: 10,height: 10,),
        Image.asset('images/user.png', width: 30.0),
        SizedBox(width: 10,height: 10,),
        Image.asset('images/user.png', width: 30.0),
        SizedBox(width: 10,height: 10,),
        Image.asset('images/user.png', width: 30.0),
        SizedBox(width: 10,height: 10,),
        Image.asset('images/user.png', width: 30.0),
        SizedBox(width: 10,height: 10,),
        Image.asset('images/user.png', width: 30.0),
      ],
    ),
  ),
```

Comment: and this answer work for me too. how can I dont think like that. hehe

once again thank you so much. god bless you ::)